# how should i get the touch of specific object in ARCore?(Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

If i have two different objects on my surface view how should i get the touch of specific object? So i can only to pass that particular object for rendering and i can just enable the rotation of that particular object only.

It is possible with Radio Button selection mode demo link is given below but i need it in on object selection i don't want to put the radio button : 
[Demo Using Radio Button same as per my requirement](https://www.raywenderlich.com/170520/getting-started-arcore-kotlin)

Comment: You could perform a raycast. I can explain more if you show what you have tried so far, we're not here to write your code.